# Json Path Extractor expression to get values when substring is present

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I am using JMeter's "JSON Extractor" and I try to get all "recipients" arrays from the following response, if one of their elements contains a specific string. To be more exact, I have the following JSON response:

```
    {
        "size": "12",
        "sender": "<no-reply@mywebsite.com>",
        "recipients": [
            "<john@testsite.com>",
            "<marry@anothersite.com>",
            "<amartin@anothersite.com>"
        ],
        "subject": "super mail",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "size": "35",
        "sender": "<no-reply@mywebsite.com>",
        "recipients": [
            "<apolodor@testsite.com>",
            "<paul@anothersite.com>"
        ],
        "subject": "super subject",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "size": "41",
        "sender": "<no-reply@mywebsite.com>",
        "recipients": [
            "<ricardo@testsite.com>",
            "<mariah@anothersite.com>",
            "<amartin@anothersite.com>"
        ],
        "subject": "nothing special",
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

And I want to find all the recipients that have at least one element containing the substring "mar".
The expression that gets the closest answer to what I need is:

`$..*.[?(@.recipients.* contains '<marry@anothersite.com>')].recipients`

This will return :

`Result[0]=["<john@testsite.com>","<marry@anothersite.com>","<amartin@anothersite.com>"]`

How can I change the filter so that I get:

```
Result[0]=["<john@testsite.com>","<marry@anothersite.com>","<amartin@anothersite.com>"]
Result[1]=["<ricardo@testsite.com>","<mariah@anothersite.com>","<amartin@anothersite.com>"]
```

as both "marry" and "mariah" contain the substring "mar".

`$..*.[?(@.recipients.* contains 'mar')].recipients`
doesn't work as "contains" refers most probably to an element of the arrays and not to a substring of an element.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use JSON Extractor for this, your requirement could be implemented using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide), however it's implemented in such a weird way that it doesn't return a valid JSON in case of arrays and it makes any advanced usage impossible or at least inconvenient resulting in coming up with a boilerplate transformations and mappings.

The fastest and the easiest option would be implementing the filtering using [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language functions.

Example code:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

response.recipients.findAll { recipient -> recipient.findAll { it.contains('mar') } }.eachWithIndex { result, index ->
    def emails = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(result).toString()
    log.info(emails)
    vars.put('myVar_' + (index + 1), emails)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Finding Elements in Collections in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-collections-find-elements)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: The question has been answered and the solution works as expected - thanks, and for the documentation too. How could I extend the solution so that the final result contains only the emails having the "mar" substring? I tried to extend the "def emails = ..." by changing the "result" to "result -> result.findAll { it.contains('mar') }"  but it doesn't work.